# DateTime to int

Tags: c#

How to covert DateTime to int

```
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  int va = now.Year;

  // error here
  int vd = int.Parse(mYear.Value.ToShortDateString()); 

  result = Convert.ToString(va - vd);
```

> Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: what value of `vd` were you expecting?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve ? It appears you want to find the difference between two dates, why not directly subtract them

Comment: what is mYear in your sample?

Comment: mYear is a feild with the date.

Comment: `toShortDateString()` converts a DateTime object to a string containing the month, day, and year, and is formatted for your locale, eg. MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: What value are you trying to get into `vd`? *Of what type* is `mYear`? Show more code, especially its declaration! Why do you think `int.Parse` should successfully parse a *date string*??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mYear` is of Type `DateTime` - Just do it like you did with `now`:

```
int vd = mYear.Year;
```

If it's a string like "2014", use something like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(mYear, "yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.90).aspx) is going to do with escape chars.

```
//    The example displays the following output: 
//    Displaying short date for en-US culture: 
//    6/1/2009 (Short Date String) 
//    6/1/2009 ('d' standard format specifier)
```

@ ElGavilan commented to the same effect while I was posting.